# How to convert a string to character by character in Android?

Tags: android

I have Edittext field that the user can enter their name. I want to check it with alphabets for how many times a letter comes.
Which is the best way to do this?

I tried the below code for getting each character from the string but error occurring? I appreciate it if any one can help.

```
name=(EditText)findViewById(gami.Numerology.R.id.inputUI);
String a=name.getText().toString();

for ( int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++ )

{  
           c = a.charAt(i);

            if (c=='s')
            {
            s=1; //like this for all characters
            }

         }
```

I just put this in a click event of button.

Comment: Are you counting the number of each letter. eg number of "a" , number of "b", etc?

Comment: Tanja thank you,   Yes ofcourse that's I need

Comment: Lews Therin thank you.    The error is E/AndroidRuntime(5863): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Answer (score 2):

```
 //declare the original String object
    String strOrig = "Hello World";
    //declare the char array
    char[] stringArray;


//convert string into array using toCharArray() method of string class
stringArray = strOrig.toCharArray();

//display the array
for(int index=0; index < stringArray.length; index++)
//check of character appearance
```

Comment: I used this method also but an happening like this.. 10-07 04:14:25.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5863): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Comment: Yes thanks it works, the error was i need to convert the chracter to string to disply.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hashmap or some sort of dictionary in Java. 
Rough example since I don't know how to use Hashmap in Java:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (Character c: name)
{
    counter.put(c, counter.get(c) == null ? 1 : counter.get(c)++);
}
```